# Fetch URI from a local php file and include it in another local php file inside href tag

Tags: php

Suppose,

My css file is hosted in `https://cdn.domain.com/css/style.css`

Now my main site is `https://www.domain.com`
Here I have a file in `https://www.domain.com/scripts/source/link.php` and it only contains the URI of the cdn site:

**A:** `https://cdn.domain.com/`

Now, in my index file I want to include that css file but using the link.php file like:

**B:** `<link rel="stylesheet" href="<? include 'scripts/source/link.php'; ?>css/style.css" />`

I know the previous code won't work like

**C:** `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.domain.com/css/style.css" />`

So to achieve **C**, what should be in **A** or in **B**?

Comment: So you simply want to get the content of `https://www.domain.com/scripts/source/link.php`? Does 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272228/how-do-i-load-a-php-file-into-a-variable answer your question?

Comment: If link.php doesn't contain anything else than `https://cdn.domain.com/` B should work.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

In section **B**,

```
<?php
ob_start();
include "link.php";
$myvar = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean(); 
?>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<? echo $myvar."style.css";?>" />
```

Comment: BTW: Think about using `ob_start()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php