# PHP includes not working within file_get_contents

Tags: php, include, file-get-contents

I have the following code which sets a variable as the contents of a file and then uses that variable in the template file.

```
$content = file_get_contents('./section_body.php');

include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/template.php';
```

This was working fine until I added an include into `section_body.php`. The contents of this include do not get rendered to the page.

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Here's the code for section_body.php if it helps:

```
<?php 

include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/controllers/category_list.php';

?>

<div>
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p>dfg kjdfsghsd fkjghdjksfg jdhksfg kjsdfg hjskdf ghjsdfg kdhjsfg </p>
</div>
```

Comment: file_get_contents does not execute php code , it just read the file as text or say binary.

Comment: That makes sense! Can you point me the right way for a solution to the problem? Would I be right in thinking output buffering is the best way to go?

Comment: I think this answer is for you, [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272228/how-do-i-load-a-php-file-into-a-variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your trying to build an template structure for your website. There are a lot existing, which would be also a choice.

You could work with the [PHP output control functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php), start with [`ob_start()`].(http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php)

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "section_body.php";
    $content = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/template.php';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can get rendered content as following without file_get_contents() so that you can reduce processing time.

```
 ob_start();
 include('./section_body.php');
 $content=ob_get_clean();
```