# Executing PHP File and Putting Results In a String

Tags: php

I have the following to read a file and assign to a string:

```
$insert_html = file_get_contents('view.php');
```

The **view.php** file itself looks like:

```
<div>This is price of your item: <?php echo $price; ?></div>
```

However, the PHP inside the file is not being executed. Both `eval()` and `include` don't quite give me what I want. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: (quoted:) "*Both eval() and include don't quite give me what I want*" For what else are you looking then?

Comment: You can check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272228/how-do-i-load-a-php-file-into-a-variable

Comment: That's exactly what I want @littleibex. But the second answer works for me!

Comment: @GuillermoPhillips Yes, I was also thinking that second answer is more appropriate.

Comment: can you change your view.php?

Answer (score 0):

You can use that `$insert_html = exec('view.php');` but I don't think it's the best way.

Regards.