# php code inside divs inside a php array

Tags: php, html

Hi guys sorry for the bad english :)  i have this code below that echo the some divs defined inside the array
i want to include a php page (example below ) inside those divs  :

```
<?php $items =array(         
        '<div id="o-31" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3" > <div id="mydid"  >   </div></div>',  


             '<div id="o-36" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"  ><div  class="demo-content bg-alt" >.col-sm-8</div></div>', 


             '<div id="o-37" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"  ><div class="demo-content bg-alt" >.col-sm-8</div></div>', 


      '<div id="o-38" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><div id="mydid"  > </div></div>'
     );

?> 
      <?php 
        for($i = 0; $i <= 3; $i++){

        echo $items[$i];

        }
      ?>
```

i cant see how i can add a php code inside the div i tried :

```
 '<div id="o-31" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3" > <div id="mydid"  > 

         <?php
      $ccc= "ff";
  $tablelink2=$_SESSION['hes_2'];
 $tabletitle2=$_SESSION['hes_1'];
 $tableimg2= $_SESSION['hes_3'];
     include('hes_2.php');
     ?>

        </div></div>',
```

and

```
'<div id="o-31" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3" > <div id="mydid"  >'



     <?php
          $ccc= "ff";
      $tablelink2=$_SESSION['hes_2'];
     $tabletitle2=$_SESSION['hes_1'];
     $tableimg2= $_SESSION['hes_3'];
         include('hes_2.php');
         ?>

            '</div></div>',
```

also not working :( ?

Comment: This makes no sense. What are you really trying to do? Putting php code in php arrays....why?

Comment: I think you need to start from Book 1 chapter 1 Paragraph 1 and work out what it is you are actually trying to achieve

Comment: session_start(); is exist on top of the code?

Comment: In case this is what you're thinking: You cannot  put PHP code in a div to be run later. PHP runs on the server. You can only put the ouput of PHP code in a div.

Comment: yes session is started , im gonna change to some GET and bring all the code to a new php file

Comment: come on guys why the negative votes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all,

I'll recommend using **sprintf** and **vsprintf** to tidy up your code,

```
$items =array(         
    '<div id="o-31" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><div id="mydid">%s</div></div>',  
    '<div id="o-36" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><div class="demo-content bg-alt">.col-sm-8</div></div>', 
    '<div id="o-37" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><div class="demo-content bg-alt">.col-sm-8</div></div>', 
    '<div id="o-38" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><div id="mydid">%s</div></div>'
);

$items[0] = sprintf($items[0], 'Item 0');
$items[3] = sprintf($items[3], 'Item 3');

echo vsprintf(str_repeat("%s\n", count($items)), $items);
```

Next, about the include file. There is a work around here,

[How to load a php file into a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272228/how-do-i-load-a-php-file-into-a-variable)

To implement,

```
function inc2var($file){
    ob_start();
    include $file;
    $var = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $var;
}

$ccc = "ff";
$tablelink2 = $_SESSION['hes_2'];
$tabletitle2 = $_SESSION['hes_1'];
$tableimg2 = $_SESSION['hes_3'];

$items[0] = sprintf($items[0], inc2var('hes_2.php'));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: hey thanks i was changing the hole code , but your answer kept me , first time i see this ob method , i am reading about it

Comment: it works but there is error undefined variables $ccc ... those variables are used in the php file – thanks

Comment: just move the variables to the function thanks man very much

Answer (score 0):

Try making a separate PHP file and passing it a parameter via address line: `somefile.php?a=5&b=7&c=hello` etc, then read those parameters in the target file using `$_GET['varname']` like `$_GET['a']`. If that `['a']` is not going to be fixed, you can use double quotes and a variable name: `$_GET["$varname"]`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks i will try your idea it looks ok

Answer (score 0):

You cannot embed PHP within PHP:

```
<?php $items =array(         
        '<div id="o-31" [...snip...]
         <?php ... ?>
```

You're already in PHP mode on the first line, and in the middle of a PHP string, which means that the SECOND `<?php` tag is not a PHP tag. It's the characters `<`, `?`, `p`, etc... becoming part of this string you're building.

You have to break OUT of the string, do whatever you want, then go BACK into string mode. e.g.

```
$str = "foo <?php bar() ?> baz"; // will not work
$str = "foo " . bar() . " baz"; //works fine
```

Comment: okey but its not the case here ?